# booting from external hard drive

Tags: boot, uefi

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 on an external drive as I don't want to dual boot my new Windows Laptop. As the laptop is in uefi mode and the external drive is Ext4, this is not seen by the Laptop. How do I get the Laptop to see the Ext 4 external Drive to allow me to boot into Ubuntu Mate 18.04? Is there a bootloader that I can use on another USB Drive?

I have a Dell Inspiron loaded with Windows 10 and in its default factory setting will allow a USB formatted to Fat16, 32 or NTFS to be recognised at switch on. By use of the F12 I can boot from a USB formatted in Fat32, however it will not recognise Ext4. The Ext Drive was built on another machine already running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I can run the ext Drive if I alter all of the BIOS settings but because of the way Dell have built the Laptop Windows is then recognised as an illegal copy.. hence the need to boot from a USB formatted in Fat32 to allow me to access the Ext Drive and Ubuntu. The Ext Drive was built using a USB made from a live cd.

Comment: 1) The external drive is attached by USB, right? 2) The internal drive has Windows 10 from the factory, right? 3) Then, if the external drive was installed after formatting it with a GPT partition table, it should be bootable. Confirm 1) and 2) and give detail on how you generated the LiveUSB used to prepare the external drive. Did you use http://rufus.ie and specify GPT? please click [edit] above and answer these questions to help us help you. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Did you use this laptop for installation or another one?  Have you adjusted bios in this one to boot from USB first.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to create a Fat32 Partition at start of Ext Drive and then install Ubuntu Mate 18.04 to the later part of the Ext Drive obviously in Ext4 format. Install grub in the fat32 partition boot sector and all works well with no need to keep going in to BIOS. To install Ubuntu, Secure Boot had to be disabled but once installed it can be re-enabled.